Did more Puerto Ricans soldiers really die in Vietnam War than from any state?
The Puerto Rican church seems to say so:

In this letter to former President Trump, Roberto O. Gonzalez Nieves, archbishop of San Juan de Puerto Rico, says:

More Puerto Rican soldiers died in the Vietnam War as part of the United States military than soldiers from any state of the United States.

Is that statement correct ?

Have you checked Wikipedia's Puerto Ricans in the Vietnam War? Does this answer your question? If not, please edit your question to explain why. Thank you.

@LarsBosteen - I checked it myself, and couldn't find that info in there. Had to go running to the national archives...

@MCW What is "the existing narrative" here?

@MCW Correct. Plus, I don't doubt any narrative, I'm only inquiring about the apparent contradiction between the tiny size of Puerto Rico and the huge number of deaths.

No, it doesn't appear to be the case.
The US state or territory with the most KIA in Vietnam was, unsurprisingly, the one with the largest population: California, which according to the National Archives, had 5,575 "fatal casualties" from the Vietnam conflict. New York would have been second with 4,119. Puerto Rico had "only" 345.
World Population Review has a handy map that breaks casualties down by state. This isn't fatal casualties, and their source for numbers appears to be very different than the National Archive, and it doesn't include PR(!!) but it should give you an idea of the relative proportions:

So the Archbishop appears to be quite wrong on this matter.
Now people mix up absolute and per-capita numbers in public statements all the time, and its usually the latter number that you really want. However, it appears Puerto Rico's Vietnam death rate was about 123 deaths per million 1972 citizens, while California's was more like 271. So it looks like California has them beat there too.
I'm told Vietnam death numbers can be all over the place (as you can see by comparing the numbers in the key of that map to what I got from the National Archives). There's a further different set of  numbers up at the US Army's website, which a quick bit of math show me the per-capita numbers are still in CA's favor, but not by nearly as much. So it seems possible there's some number or combination of them somewhere that shows otherwise from which this factoid was drawn.

Did you consider that the Archbishop might have included people of Puerto Rican ancestry, but living in various states rather than Puerto Rico itself, in his calculation?

@Spencer - In fact I did consider that. However, I'm not sure how I'd get that information (and I'm not sure how he would have either). It also wouldn't be comparing apple to apples if we look at it that way. Perhaps Oklahoma gets to claim all our California Dust Bowl Okies too?

Another interesting statistic to look at would be 'number of death per soldier sent to Vietnam' instead of per total population. It seems possible that Puerto-Rican soldiers were sent to more dangerous places and hence had a higher casualty number per soldier but I didn't look at the data.

@quarague - Not a bad idea. From a quick googling it looks like there were nearly 10x more Californians sent there than Puerto Ricans. However, it looks like CA had more than 10x the fatal casualties. I got the participation figures for the two states from different sources though, so the numbers might not be a good comparison. I'd need numbers I trust better to stick that in an answer.

@T.E.D. To be fair, Boricuas are an ethnic group, unlike Okies, so the Puerto Rican population outside of Puerto Rico is meaningful and defined.  Wikipedia suggests that number is 455 fatal Boricua casualties in the Vietnam War (32% higher), but I can not find the source which is only listed as: Department of Defense; "Number of Puerto Ricans serving in the U.S. Armed Forces during National Emergencies"

@T.E.D. - A fair number of Oklahomans definitely had a distinct ethnic identity from Californians during the Dust Bowl era. Their descendants now, perhaps not so much. But then, perhaps something similar could be said about many descendants of Puerto Ricans in the continental USA after four generations as well. Anyway, it would be an odd way of measuring it either way—no one doubts that "Chinese American" is an ethnicity, but Chinese-American soldiers in World War II don't get counted in with China's casualties in the conflict.

The reason for the different number of casualties on the Army's website is because it only lists casualties from the U.S. Army, not the Marines, Navy, Air Force, and Coast Guard (except in the case of WWII, where the Army numbers did include the Army Air Corps, which was then part of the Army, but soon after became the Air Force.) This is noted at the bottom of the linked source. So, those numbers don't necessarily show that PR had a different per capita ratio of casualties than the other, but just that more Californians were in the other branches.

@reirab - Yeah. I saw some sites (eg, the one I got the PR deaths from) just tallied all deaths from state residents while serving in the military during the war years. That's obviously imperfect too, although the vast majority of those deaths were probably war-related. This kind of thing is why the numbers are all over the place.

any information on the casualty rate as a percentage of the troops deployed from the territory or state?
